# Wait for records to be loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to wait that records are loaded in my app, but this doesn't work:

```
    var sectors = this.get('store').find('sector');
    sectors.on('didLoad', function() {
        console.log("loaded: " + this.get('formLoaded'));
    });
```

It says that "Object [object Object] has no method 'on'",
what am I doing wrong?

Update:
following chopper's suggestion, i get a new error since i use this to get data from the server to fill a select view:

i have a controller like this:

```
App.FormController = Em.Controller.extend({
sectors: function() {
    var sectors = this.get('store').find('sector');
    return sectors;
}.property(),
accesslevels: function() {
    var accesslevels = this.get('store').find('accesslevel');
    return accesslevels;
}.property(),
equipments: function() {
    var equipments = this.get('store').find('equipment');
    return equipments;
}.property(),
difficulties: function() {
    var difficulties = this.get('store').find('difficulty');
    return difficulties;
}.property()
```

});

and in the template i have:

```
sectors: {{view Ember.Select id="settore" contentBinding="sectors" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.descrizione"}}

access levels: {{view Ember.Select id="liv_acc" contentBinding="accesslevels" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.descrizione"}}
```

and so on;
this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't because i have to wait that records coming from all find() are loaded before rendering the views; I tried as written above with "on('didLoad')" following the Ember doc, but doesn't work; can you please help me to find why?

Comment: my idea was to set a controller's property (formLoad) to true after all find() have finished; and then use this in the template like:  {{if formLoad}} ... render the view

Comment: did the below answer work for you?

Comment: I've added a new answer; as explained there, I was thinking that the error i'm getting sometimes, was due to the view rendering before the model are loaded... But probably I was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [promise](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/) returned by `find`/`findAll`:

```
 var sectors = this.get('store').findAll('sector').then( function(data) {
    console.log("loaded: " + data);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your suggestions, and other answers, i finally decided for this solution to load multi-model (using model hook in the Route handler):

```
model: function(params) {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
        settori: this.get('store').findAll('sector'),
        attrezzature: this.get('store').findAll('equipment'),
        difficolta: this.get('store').findAll('difficulty'),
        livelliaccesso: this.get('store').findAll('accesslevel'),
        sino: [{id: 0, descrizione: "No"}, {id: 1, descrizione: "Sì"}]
    });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.setProperties(model);
}
```

The RSVP should ensure that all promises are fully loaded before the view is rendered;

In any case i'm facing a strange problem: sometimes i get this error:

```
Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

This seems to be unpredictable to me: sometimes happens, then for many times no; i think it happens more the first time that i load the App;
in the docs is written that this can have something to do with "hasMany" or "belongsTo" relations in the models, but i don't have any of these in my models;

I'm developing the App locally with yeoman, and a restful server based on node js (using express) provides the data loaded from mysql (easyphp is running the mysql server)

Someone knows what's wrong?